# Plotly: How to remove unused values from x_axis

Tags: python, plotly

How can I remove empty values from x_axis, so there is no huge gap between bars? In another way, how can I make 7, 11, 13, 14 and other empty values be gone.

"""

```
from random import randint
from plotly.graph_objs import Bar, Layout
from plotly import offline

class Die:
    """A class representing a single die."""
    def __init__(self, num_sides = 6):
        self.num_sides = num_sides

    def roll(self):
        """Return a random value between 1 and the number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.num_sides)

#Created a D6.
die_1 = Die()
die_2 = Die()

#Make some rolls, and store results in a list.
results = []
for roll_num in range(10000):
    result = die_1.roll() * die_2.roll()
    results.append(result)

unique_results = sorted(set(results))

#Analyze results
frequencies = []
for value in unique_results:
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

#Visualize results
x_values = list(x for x in unique_results)
data = [Bar(x=x_values, y=frequencies)]

x_axis_config = {'title' : 'Result',  'dtick' : 1}
y_axis_config = {'title' : 'Frequency of Result'}
my_layout = Layout(title = 'Results of rolling two D6 dices multiplied by each other 10000 times',
                   xaxis=x_axis_config, yaxis=y_axis_config)
offline.plot({'data' : data, 'layout' : my_layout}, filename='d6_d6_multiply.html')
```

"""

It works fine if I set the value of x value in a next way:
"""

```
x_values = list(range(1, 19))
```

"""
But in that case, there is the wrong description under each bar.

[image: The result I have right now]

This is what is expected but with correct numbers under bars... `1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12 and so on up to 36`

[image: What's is expected but with correct numbers under bars. >>> 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,12 and so on up to 36]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the type of your x-axis to `category`

Therefore update your `x_axis_config` like this

```
x_axis_config = {'title' : 'Result',  'dtick' : 1, 'type': 'category'}
```

The result should know look like this.

[image]